# How do I remove all metadata from a quicktime movie file?

Tags: command-line, video, software-rec, privacy, quicktime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip metadata from all formats with FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg)

My camera takes .mov files as movies. How can I remove all metadata from them so I can feel confident sharing them on youtube without accidentally sharing when/where they were filmed, what type of camera I have, etc. A command line one-liner would be nice, but I can handle some GUI setup if that's the only way.

When [I asked this at askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139570/how-do-i-remove-all-metadata-from-a-quicktime-movie-file), I got an answer that only works with ubuntu's ancient version of ffmpeg.  Since I've got the latest ffmpeg, that won't work for me.  I also hope this means I'm not cross-posting since that question is "How do I do this in ubuntu?" and this question is "How do I do this in general?"