# How to strip metadata from MP3 files?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, mp3, metadata, libav

I want to strip metadata from MP3 files.

In a brief: **How to simply get a stream of pure MP3 frames out of a MP3 file** – by means of command line tools? Preferable using tools out of the box of a linux mint system.

I found [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg). I wanted to use `avconv` and tried the given hints.

slhck's hint doesn't work simply by replacing `ffmpeg` with `avconv`. The output file has no more Title and Artist information, but embedded images are retained.

The same happens with evilsoup's hint, even albeit this is a native `avconv` hint. His second hint even retains Artist, Title, and so on.

OS is Linux Mint 17.

Commandline and output of avconv:

```
$ avconv -i in.mp3 -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp3
avconv version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Aug 10 2014 18:16:02 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[mp3 @ 0x21ad1e0] max_analyze_duration reached
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, mp3, from 'in.mp3':
  Metadata:
    album_artist    : Pin
    album           : Mag
    artist          : Pin
    title           : Alo
    track           : 2/12
    date            : 201
  Duration: 00:05:20.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 281 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0.1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 2560x2560 [PAR 100:100 DAR 1:1], 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      title           : 
      comment         : Cover (front)
Output #0, mp3, to 'out.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 2560x2560 [PAR 100:100 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : 
      comment         : Cover (front)
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, stereo, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=    1 fps=  0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   11024kB time=0.01 bitrate=9030959.2kbits/s    
video:996kB audio:10027kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.007902%
```

Comment: Just to avoid confusion - what OS? I'm *guessing* Ubuntu, since avconv is specific to that, but specificity is awesome. I'd guess your *specific* issue is stripping embedded images, and I'd suggest adding that explicitly too.

Comment: Please show the full command line output from the avconv process you tried

Comment: Comments aren't allowed to be as long as needed to give output. Will add by editing.

Comment: Ok, it seems the embedded image is considered to be a stream, not metadata.
Therefore I tried

`$ avconv -i in.mp3 -map 0:0 -map_metadata -1 -c:a copy out.mp3`

and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

$ `avconv -i in.mp3 -map 0:0 -map_metadata -1 -c:a copy out.mp3`

Ref. comment – image is considered being a stream; the stream is deselected by only mention `0:0` as parameter to `-map`

Comment: Nevertheless out.mp3 begins with magic number 0x494433 ("ID3") instead of pure MP3 frames.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the metadata from the MP3 files you can use the below there tools

```
eyeD3, id3tool, id3v2
```

Example for eyeD3:

```
eyeD3 --remove-lyrics --remove-v1 *.mp3
```

Comment: Question indicates the use of linux - avconv is basically a ubuntu specific ffmpeg fork.

Comment: eyeD3 seems to work good, but is only able to modify files in place. I'm looking for a way to pipe the output.

Comment: id3tool presents no option to _remove_ tags, only options to set them.

Comment: id3v2 lacks the possibility to pipe, too. Only modify-in-place operation.