# How do I remove all metadata from a WebM file?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, exif, webm

I've tried using ffmpeg, but it seems to keep all the metadata I'm actively looking to remove.

I'm looking to remove ALL metadata, including length, bitrate, etc.
Before you say this isn't possible, yes it is, and I have multiple files that have what I'm looking to do. The files without metadata are still fully playable.

Example of what I want to do:

[image]

I've also tried `exiftool` but it doesn't work with WebMs.

I tried [the solution here](https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg) and it didn't work. The output of ffmpeg on one of the WEBMs without metadata is:

[image]

Comment: What did you try with ffmpeg? Share the output of `ffmpeg -i nometadata.webm`

Comment: Output of ffmpeg is https://i.imgur.com/mHXXVd1.png on the file without metadata.

I tried the solution on superuser here: https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg

Comment: What is the tool you're using to view metadata in the first screenshot? Have you created the file, or where did you get it from? Why would you even want a file that has no indicated length or bitrate?

Comment: @slhck It's just right-clicking on the file and clicking details on Windows 10. Can't remember where I found it.

Comment: What kind of file is the example?  What is the program/command you used to achieve this result?

Comment: @StarGeek The example is a WEBM, and I didn't make it. That's why I'm asking if anyone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the software suite MKVToolNix. A tool in it 'mkvpropedit' can be used for your purpose. It works on webm files also as it a profile of matroska. Here is an untested example.

(Try in cmd in the target's directory)

```
mkvpropedit "input.webm" --tags
```

NOTE: It might remove other useful tags too, so create a backup.

Comment: Hello, this didn't work. I figured out that the correct command was [code]mkvpropedit "input.webm" --tags all:""[/code] however that didn't work either. Thank you though!